# snowsql not able to take arguments in mac

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following .sql file and is running perfectly fine in windows but I run the same file through mac it says '"${intgdatabase}"' not found. I think there is some issue with how the variable is passed in mac.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE "${intgdatabase}"."${profileschema}".AUDIENCE_INSIGHT
(
    TOTAL_CUSTOMERS NUMBER(18,0),
    COUNTRIES NUMBER(18,0),
    US_STATES NUMBER(18,0),
    CITIES NUMBER(18,0),
    MIN_AGE NUMBER(18,0),
    MAX_AGE NUMBER(18,0),
    WOMEN NUMBER(27,6),
    MEN NUMBER(27,6),
    OTHER NUMBER(27,6)
);
```

My config.txt is:

```
admindatabase="HXP_ELT"
adminctrlschema="CTRL"
adminlogschema="LOG"
intgdatabase="HXP_SANDBOX"
profileschema="SANDBOX"
basedatabase="HXP_C360"
baseschema="BASE"
identitydatabase="IDENTITY"
decschema="DEC"
ltdschema="LTD"
vizschema="VIZ"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Mac you need to use **&varname** in your SQL file. The following setup works fine for me:

In my config file:

```
[variables]
# SnowSQL defines the variables in this section on startup.
# You can use these variables in SQL statements. For details, see
# https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-use.html#using-variables
mydatabase="SERGIU_TESTDB"
myschema="PUBLIC"
mytable="CITIBIKE_TRIPS"
```

In my SQL file:

```
$ cat my_sql.sql
SELECT * FROM &mydatabase.&myschema.&mytable LIMIT 10;
```

Result:

```
$ snowsql -c <myaccount> -f my_sql.sql
* SnowSQL * v1.2.21
Type SQL statements or !help
+------------------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+------------------+------------------------------+----------------+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+
| RIDE_ID          | RIDEABLE_TYPE | STARTED_AT              | ENDED_AT                | START_STATION_NAME         | START_STATION_ID | END_STATION_NAME             | END_STATION_ID | START_LAT |  START_LNG |     END_LAT |      END_LNG | MEMBER_CASUAL |
|------------------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+------------------+------------------------------+----------------+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------|
| 313DE7DE31EE67AB | docked_bike   | 2021-04-18 19:04:03.000 | 2021-04-18 19:08:05.000 | 9 Ave & W 45 St            |             6717 | Broadway & W 41 St           |           6560 | 40.760192 | -73.991255 | 40.75513557 | -73.98658032 | member        |
| 067F5149521BFC55 | docked_bike   | 2021-04-28 16:06:57.000 | 2021-04-28 16:26:15.000 | Cooper Square & Astor Pl   |             5712 | 11 Ave & W 41 St             |           6726 | 40.729514 | -73.990752 | 40.76030096 | -73.99884222 | member        |
| 56D4E949F3E39E69 | docked_bike   | 2021-04-24 15:21:08.000 | 2021-04-24 15:37:06.000 | Cooper Square & Astor Pl   |             5712 | 11 Ave & W 41 St             |           6726 | 40.729514 | -73.990752 | 40.76030096 | -73.99884222 | member        |
| 9800445811B8C3D7 | docked_bike   | 2021-04-27 18:04:13.000 | 2021-04-27 18:32:07.000 | Willis Ave & Bruckner Blvd |             7691 | Wards Meadow Comfort Station |           7327 | 40.805701 | -73.925177 | 40.78294    | -73.93077    | casual        |
| 0F399B83BB1454C0 | docked_bike   | 2021-04-05 17:44:09.000 | 2021-04-05 17:57:32.000 | E 33 St & 5 Ave            |             6322 | 11 Ave & W 41 St             |           6726 | 40.747659 | -73.984907 | 40.76030096 | -73.99884222 | casual        |
| 39811D971257CC03 | docked_bike   | 2021-04-23 10:12:30.000 | 2021-04-23 10:30:18.000 | Willis Ave & Bruckner Blvd |             7691 | Wards Meadow Comfort Station |           7327 | 40.805701 | -73.925177 | 40.78294    | -73.93077    | member        |
| AEFD84FD74F007A4 | docked_bike   | 2021-04-26 20:22:18.000 | 2021-04-26 20:33:36.000 | E 33 St & 5 Ave            |             6322 | 11 Ave & W 41 St             |           6726 | 40.747659 | -73.984907 | 40.76030096 | -73.99884222 | casual        |
| 96B11D92E9EC53E4 | docked_bike   | 2021-04-25 00:58:17.000 | 2021-04-25 01:04:55.000 | E 33 St & 5 Ave            |             6322 | 11 Ave & W 41 St             |           6726 | 40.747659 | -73.984907 | 40.76030096 | -73.99884222 | member        |
| 74D09B541A8469EB | docked_bike   | 2021-04-28 16:01:01.000 | 2021-04-28 16:41:36.000 | E 33 St & 5 Ave            |             6322 | 12 Ave & W 40 St             |           6765 | 40.747659 | -73.984907 | 40.76087502 | -74.00277668 | member        |
| 899B7FEA562C1BDA | docked_bike   | 2021-04-09 11:03:35.000 | 2021-04-09 11:20:27.000 | E 33 St & 5 Ave            |             6322 | Broadway & W 41 St           |           6560 | 40.747659 | -73.984907 | 40.75513557 | -73.98658032 | member        |
+------------------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+------------------+------------------------------+----------------+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+
10 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 1.312s
Goodbye!
```

Make also sure this is set to True:

```
[options]
variable_substitution = True
```